# How do I use the children and tree methods of JSONField?

Tags: peewee

Let's just say I'm using the sample data used in this [blog post](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-the-sqlite-json1-and-fts5-extensions-with-python/). How do I get a list of distinct (or not) tags from all posts using children() or tree()?

I'm thinking I will have to use children, but I'm stumped on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are now documented with examples: [children()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/sqlite_ext.html#JSONField.children) and [tree()](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/sqlite_ext.html#JSONField.tree). Here is some example code, also from the documentation:

```
class KeyData(Model):
    key = TextField()
    data = JSONField()

KeyData.create(key='a', data={'k1': 'v1', 'x1': {'y1': 'z1'}})
KeyData.create(key='b', data={'x1': {'y1': 'z1', 'y2': 'z2'}})

# We will query the KeyData model for the key and all the
# keys and values in it's data field, recursively.
kd = KeyData.data.tree().alias('tree')
query = (KeyData
         .select(kd.c.key, kd.c.value, kd.c.fullkey)
         .from_(KeyData, kd)
         .order_by(kd.c.key)
         .tuples())
print(query[:])

# PRINTS:
[('a',  None,  '{"k1":"v1","x1":{"y1":"z1"}}', '$'),
 ('b',  None,  '{"x1":{"y1":"z1","y2":"z2"}}', '$'),
 ('a',  'k1',  'v1',                           '$.k1'),
 ('a',  'x1',  '{"y1":"z1"}',                  '$.x1'),
 ('b',  'x1',  '{"y1":"z1","y2":"z2"}',        '$.x1'),
 ('a',  'y1',  'z1',                           '$.x1.y1'),
 ('b',  'y1',  'z1',                           '$.x1.y1'),
 ('b',  'y2',  'z2',                           '$.x1.y2')]
```

Comment: Thank you a ton! Peewee has been a lifesaver!